# Using Linq To Get Data By Date

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list< item > of the following

```
public class Item
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public FeedType FeedType { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Link = "";
        Title = "";
        Content = "";
        PublishDate = DateTime.Today;
        FeedType = FeedType.RSS;
    }
}
```

Which is just a parsed RSS feed, I now want to be able to query the List< item > to pull out items only with a PublishDate of today?

However I'm getting a bit lost... Can anyone shed any light please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly the goal here is to strip off the time when comparing.

Extention Method syntax

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
items.Where( item => item.PublishDate.Date == today );
```

Query syntax

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
from item in items
where item.PublishDate.Date == Today
select item
```

Comment: You might get inconsistent results when querying around midnight.

Comment: good call. Today should be extracted to a local. Also I had not seen the Today property before.

Comment: Editing to include @albin feedback and his way cooler user of Today instead of DateTime.Now.Date

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var todayItems = list.Where(item => item.PublishDate.Date == today);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the edit for extracting DateTime.Today and the Use of Today instead of DateTime.Now came from this answer. Was not in my original post. Thank @Albin I learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Item> itemList = ...;
ListItem<Item> filtered items 
                 = itemList.Where(it => it.PublishDate >= DateTime.Today).ToList()
```